# Is it possible to communicate with Microsoft Bot from cmdline?

Tags: botframework, bots

I'm trying to create a chat bot that could do command line operations. So this chat bot must be invokable from cmdline. I see different channels to communicate with the bot, but how do I communicate with it using cmdline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, communicate through C# console app (command line) you have to communicate through DirectLine channel

Essentially you have to:

1. register a Direct Line channel to get the secret key
2. create `DirectLineClient` with the secret key you got
3. start sending `Activity` through the `DirectLineClient` you created, and receive response using it as well

there is a sample project of how to use it on github you might want to have a look:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `ConsoleConnector`

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a similar class in C#?